# Angular 6: Disabling input on reactive form without disabling form control

Tags: html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

One of my forms needs special behaviour in that it needs to display a value in an input field, but it shouldn't be editable but it should be sent with the post to the api.

I tried to solve this by using `getRawValue()` but that just gave me the form values without the two disabled fields in them.

Is there any way to disable input on a form field without using the `form.disable()` function?

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="!IsNewRecord()" fxFlex="calc(40% - 14px)">
    <input matInput placeholder="Veldnaam" formControlName="FieldName" disabled>
</mat-form-field>
```

using the disabled keyword still results in the field being editable as shown here:

[image: Disabled keyword does not disable form field]

I also don't want to disable the entire form control because I won't be able to get the value from the disabled element later when I want to save the form.

So what I basically want is that visually it's disabled but the reactive form can still read/change the value shown

EDIT:
This is what happens when I disable the `FieldName` control and use `getRawValue()` to take the raw form values.

[image: disabled]

This is what happens when I do the same but don't disable the control from my component ts file.

[image: not disabled]

As you can see with the first case, `FieldName` is `null` and in the second case it's filled.

Comment: use `getRawValue()` then, what is the issue with it ?

Comment: This screenshot will show you that I don't get the disabled form fields when I use `getRawValue()` https://imgur.com/a/jX7Zeot

Comment: I can't see screenshots. Consider making a [mcve] to reproduce your issue

Comment: then you're doing something else wrong as `getRawValue` sole purpose is to get whole formgroup value, regardless of `disabled` status

Comment: that's going to take a lot of time for me to do right now. But as I said, I don't want to use `getRawValue()` as it's not the solution I am looking for in this case.

Comment: Maybe something goes wrong when it tries to read all the values from the form? in the screenshot I posted before it shows that `FieldName = null` even though on the form it shows `LastName` as the value. Due to the size and amount of abstraction in this application I am unable to make a minimal verifiable example unfortunately

Comment: @trichetriche I edited my question and added some images and context to show what happens when I disable my form control. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Maybe it wasn't clear enough : **I can't see screenshots**. But I definitely can go on https://stackblitz.io, and so can you (it's even one of the requirements listed in [ask] : make a [mcve]).

Comment: Yes but as I noted twice now as well, this application is too big to just size down and make make a minimal application for. I'm sorry.

Comment: The `disabled` attribute really should do the trick. It works with all my reactive forms, though I don't use the Material library. Have you tried inspecting the element to see what happens to it?